# how to get a node value in Xpath - Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath, rss

I've got a section of XML that looks like this:

```
<entry>
<id>tag:example.com,2005:Release/343597</id>
<published>2012-04-10T11:29:19Z</published>
<updated>2012-04-10T12:04:41Z</updated>
<link type="text/html" href="http://example.com/projects/example1" rel="alternate"/>
<title>example1</title>
</entry>
```

I need to grab the link `http://example.com/projects/example1` from this block.  I'm not sure how to do this.  To get the title of the project I use this code:

```
String title1 = children.item(9).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

where `children` is the `getChildNodes()` object for the `<entry> </entry>` block.  But I keep getting `NullPointerExceptions` when I try to get the node value for the `<link>` node in a similar way.  I see that the XML code is different for the `<link>` node, and I'm not sure what it's value is.... Please advise!

Comment: Do you need the XPath syntax for this? Or you need the Java API syntax?

Comment: Ahh, good question, looking for the Java API syntax.  But I got it working, see below.  Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The xpath expression to get that node is

```
//entry/link/@href
```

In java you can write

```
Document doc = ... // your XML document
XPathExpression xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//entry/link/@href");
String href = xp.evaluate(doc);
```

Then if you need to get the `link` value of the entry with a specific `id` you can change the xpath expression to

```
//entry[id='tag:example.com,2005:Release/343597']/link/@href
```

Finally if you want to get all the links in the documents, if the document has many entry elements you can write

```
Document doc = ... // your XML document
XPathExpression xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//entry/link/@href");
NodeList links = (NodeList) xp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
// and iterate on links
```

Comment: Thanks dash1e, you pushed me in the right direction.  Using the syntax you provided I was able to evaluate the compiled Xpath expression (returning the results as a `NODESET`).  I then made a NodeList from the result (the NODESET), and then I iterated through with a while loop to grab all of the links from the RSS page I'm reading.  Thank you very much :).

Comment: I add to the answer the `NodeList` example too. For completeness.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the complete code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("test.xml");
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//entry/link/@href");
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
         System.out.println(nodes.item(i));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Phani, that's exactly what I did.